# Unable to print with wifi

Tags: wireless-networking

Epson SX235W staus sheet states connected to router but wifi light is still flashing orange and unable to print using wifi. I have tried resetting the router;resetting wifi on the printer but to no avail.

Comment: The WiFi light is flashing orange - WiFi connection error. Press the Wi-Fi button on the printer to clear the error and try again.

Comment: [Product Light Status](https://files.support.epson.com/docid/cpd5/cpd51359/source/troubleshooting/reference/xp241/problem_light_status_xp241.html)